# Get a list of SQL Server Agent Jobs

Tags: sql-server

I've got an extensive selection of these to add to a spreadsheet and don't want to go through by hand.
What it the T-SQL command(s) to generate a list of SQL Server Agent Jobs?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

On each server, you can query the sysjobs table in the msdb. For instance:

```
SELECT job_id, [name] FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs;
```

Comment: Thanks, I think you just beat me to the punch so you get the prize!

Answer (score 26):

```sql
-- List of all the jobs currently running on server
SELECT
     job.job_id,
     notify_level_email,
     name,
     enabled,
     description,
     step_name,
     command,
     server,
     database_name
FROM
    msdb.dbo.sysjobs job
INNER JOIN 
    msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps steps        
ON
    job.job_id = steps.job_id
WHERE
    job.enabled = 1 -- remove this if you wish to return all jobs
```

Comment: Can you format the SQL?

Answer (score 6):

Here is my contribution - also gets the category name and filters out the report server jobs.

```
SELECT  sysjobs.name 'Job Name',
        syscategories.name 'Category',
        CASE [description]
          WHEN 'No Description available.' THEN ''
          ELSE [description]
        END AS 'Description'
FROM    msdb.dbo.sysjobs
        INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.syscategories ON msdb.dbo.sysjobs.category_id = msdb.dbo.syscategories.category_id
WHERE   syscategories.name <> 'Report Server'
ORDER BY sysjobs.name
```

Answer (score 2):

My boss actually sorted out what I was after - this gave me the list I was after.

USE msdb
SELECT     name
FROM         sysjobs