# check which SQL server jobs run between 5AM - 11PM

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get a list of SQL Server Agent Jobs](https://serverfault.com/questions/14524/get-a-list-of-sql-server-agent-jobs)

is there a way to query the job schedule DB, and list out the jobs names, their schedules, frequency, and filter them, such that if I need can see which jobs run between 5AM -11PM everyday.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [SQL Server Agent tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181367.aspx). Specifically [SysJobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189817.aspx) for the actual jobs and then [SysJobHistory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174997.aspx) for dates and times.